# swift4 : how to animate UIView with NSLayoutConstraint

Tags: swift4, nslayoutconstraint

i want to change width of uiview1 (that created by NSLayoutConstraint visual format language) by animation

this is my codes:

```
var constraintArray : [NSLayoutConstraint] = []

constraintArray += NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-10-[uiview1]-10-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict)

constraintArray += NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-10-[uiview2]-10-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict)

constraintArray += NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-10-[uiview3]-10-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict)

constraintArray += NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-100-[uiview1]-20-[uiview2]-30-[uiview3]-30-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraintArray)


func changeUIViewWidth{

    //i don't know how to change width of uiview1 by animation
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 3){
       self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

how i can do this?

Answer (score 1):

In your case it's going to be challenging because you do not have any explicit width constraint for `uiview1` that you can change in code. The closest thing you have would be by inspecting the constraints in

```
constraintArray += NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-10-[uiview1]-10-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict)
```

and adjust each constraint (there should be two constraints) returned from that line and change their `constant`.

```
let uiview1Constraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-10-[uiview1]-10-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict)

...

// Make uiview1 thinner
uiview1Constraints[0].constant = 20
uiview1Constraints[1].constant = 20
UIView.animate(withDuration: 3) {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

I'd recommend you use `NSLayoutAnchor` to create constraints. It's simpler and easier to read and also less error prone. You can still manipulate `constant` directly after creating them.

Comment: first i want to thank you for your answer and yes you are right it simpler and easier but if i use NSLayoutAnchor need more code lines (imagine i have 3 or 4 UIView in ViewController) right?